# How can I do this again? in C

Tags: c, arrays

```
#define G 10
int main(){
int grid[G][G],c,x;
for(c=1;c<=5;c++){
    for(x=1;x<=5;x++){
        if(c+x<=5)
            grid[c][x]=+1;
        else if(c+x>=7)
            grid[c][x]=-1;
        else
            grid[c][x]=0;

        printf("%2d\t ",grid[c][x]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

its output is 
[image]
Which is what I really wanted to do but now I need to make it look like
[image]

and now I don't have any idea on how to do it, it's hurting my head now

Comment: okay so I need the output to display like the image I showed(The one with blue and red),

Comment: hope you are aware of that arrays in C start at 0, not 1

Comment: As @claptrap noted, first figure out how to define and set the values of a 5X5 grid as C arrays. However, the array is unnecessary in this program except as a conceptual framework since you are printing each computed value immediately. In any case, first think about what must be true of the c and x indices for the diagonal of the result grid to be all zeros. Then work out what the relationship between c and x must be for all values above the diagonal to be the same value and for all values below the diagonal to be a different value. Ignore C while you do that, then write the code.

Comment: I always wonder, how is it possible, that someone writes such a complex piece of code and suddently stops being able to continue to do a simple change. Was that some example or a tutorial?

Comment: @Ink tried to explain it in details.Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561674/how-can-i-do-this-again-in-c/20561784#20561784

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this

```
for(c=0; c<5; c++) {     /* arrays start at 0, not 1. */
  for(x=0; x<5; x++) {   /* arrays start at 0, not 1. */
    if (c == x) {        /* looking at your output, the 0's occur when c == x */
      grid[c][x] = 0;
    } else if (c > x) {  /* the -1 when c > x */
      grid[c][x] = -1;
    } else {             /* obviously c > x */
      grid[c][x] = 1;
    }
    /* nothing else changed */
    printf("%2d\t ",grid[c][x]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple, you have three distinct *cases*:

- if both `c` and `x` are equal, your grid shows zero
- if `x` is greater than `c`, your grid shows 1
- else (ie, when `x` is less than `c`), your grid shows -1

Basically, we've written the if-else structure you need in your loop to get the desired output:

```
if (c == x) grid[c][x] = 0;
else if (x > c) grid[c][x] = 1;
else grid[c][x] = -1;
```

Thus, the full code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define G 10
int main()
{
    int grid[G][G],c,x;
    for(c=0;c<5;++c)
    {//zero indexed
        for(x=0;x<5;++x)
        {//perhaps change 5 with G, or another macro or some int
            if(c == x) grid[c][x] = 0;
            else if (c < x) grid[c][x] = 1;//1 is fine, the + is not required
            else grid[c][x] = -1;
            printf("%2d\t ",grid[c][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which [***as you can see on this codepad***](http://codepad.org/yR8mVq3d) works just fine.
*note:*
As I said, the `+` in `+1` is optional. I'd even advise against it. If I happen to come across a statement like `some_int = +1;` I might assume that it's a bug, and it was supposed to read `some_int += 1;`, which is a different thing all together.

Answer (score 1):

The major diagonal of matrix is collection of elements that meet  `row==column` condition. Plus we know that row and column elements above(right from) diagonal   meet `row<column`, and below ones `row>column` condition. And here is how to make that matrix and while making we will show them :

```
#define G 5 
int grid[G][G], row, column;
for (row =0; row < G; row++) {
    for (column =0; column <  G; column++) {
        if (row<column)
            grid[row][column] = 1;
        else if (row>column)
            grid[row][column] = -1;
        else
            grid[row][column] = 0;

        printf("%2d\t ", grid[row][column]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And here is  output:

```
 0        1       1       1       1      
-1        0       1       1       1      
-1       -1       0       1       1      
-1       -1      -1       0       1      
-1       -1      -1      -1       0
```

And Here is what was your problem.

- You chose  minor (secondary) diagonal isntead of main
- Your index handling  done manually .Like you calculated conditions manually. It is not good

And here is how you should do for minor diagonal without calculating condition manually

```
  #define G 5
int grid[G][G], row, column ;
for(row=0;row<G;row++){
    for(column=0;column< G;column++){
        if(row+column<G-1)
            grid[row][column]=1;
        else if(row+column>G-1)
            grid[row][column]=-1;
        else /*minor diagonal meet  row==(G-1)-column  //G-1 cause index begins from 0*/
            grid[row][column]=0;

        printf("%2d\t ",grid[row][column]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now `Swap` the `first` and `last` columns of your matrix then `second` and `second last`. Thats it

Answer (score 0):

[image: Example]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define G 10
int i,j;
int grid[G][G];
int main() {
    for(i=0; i<G; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<G; j++) {
            if(i==j) grid[i][j]=0;
            else if(i<j) grid[i][j]=1;
            else if(i>j) grid[i][j]=-1;
            printf("%2d\t", grid[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your program as below :

1,`for(c=1;c<=5;c++)` -->`for(c=5;c>=1;c--)`

2, `grid[c][x]=+1;`  --> `grid[c][x]=-1;`

3, `grid[c][x]=1;`  --> `grid[c][x]=+1;`

```
#define G 10
int main(){

int grid[G][G],c,x;

for(c=5;c>=1;c--){

for(x=1;x<=5;x++){    
    if(c+x<=5)
        grid[c][x]=-1;
    else if(c+x>=7)
        grid[c][x]= 1;
    else
        grid[c][x]=0;

    printf("%2d\t ",grid[c][x]);
}
printf("\n");
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a 2D matrix, where the matrix is diagonally zero, upper triangle would be 1, and lower triangle would be -1. 
So,

```
if **row == column** , then assign 0 to diagonal. (**grid[row][column] = 0**)
else if , **row < column**, then assign 1 to upper triangle. (*grid[row][column*] = 1)
else, **row > column**, then assign -1 to lower triangle. (*grid[row][column] = -1*)
```